# Is hidden() a reserved function of javascript

Tags: javascript, hidden, reserved

Of these two, only gidden() works.

```
<span onclick="hidden()">hello</span>
<span onclick="gidden()">world</span>

<script type="text/javascript"><!--
    function hidden() {
         alert("hello");
    }
    function gidden() {
         alert("world");
    }
--></script>
```

Is hidden() a reserved function of javascript? Cause that is the only thing I can think of for this to make sense. If so, what does it do?

Comment: Ha soory. I'm a bit new to this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**, It is a reserved word. You'd better avoid the **[following identifiers](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/reserved.htm)** as names of JavaScript variables. These are predefined names of implementation-dependent JavaScript objects, methods, or properties.

**here is the list of all [JavaScript Reserved Words](http://www.quackit.com/javascript/javascript_reserved_words.cfm)**

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hmm that's odd. Thanks though.

Comment: But do you know what `hidden` is for? In FF `typeof hidden` returns "undefined", where `typeof someotherthingsfromthatlist` will return "object" or "function". I guess given that `checkbox` and `radio` are also on that list `hidden` is in the same category as them?

Comment: Well, no, it's not a *reserved* word. It's a word with special meaning in some JS implementations. It's not the same - most(?) reserved words will throw an error if you try to use it as a variable name, for example.

Comment: According to this: http://javascript.about.com/od/reference/g/shidden.htm Its not a reserved word, but usually all the names of predefined Classes and Objects are considered as reserved. and should not be used as variable or function names.

Comment: There should be a difference between `Hidden` and `hidden` shouldn't there? I mean, that... almostreservedword shouldn't interfere with my function because of the case change.